# Ways to evaluate math expressions

Tags: python, math

What are some approaches to evaluate an expression such as `((1 + 1) * 2) - 3`?
Right now I am converting it to postfix form `1 1 + 2 * 3 -` and then evaluate that one.
I'd like to know if there are better approaches than this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, no, those answers pointed me to use other libraries to evaluate the expression. Here I'd like to know some ways to implement a simple python eval() function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but the Expression must be between parentheses
for example : ((4-6)+(7/9)+3) should be (((4-6)+(7/9))+3)

```
def evalu(express):
    operat,numbers=[],[]
    for i in express:
        if i =='(':
            pass
        elif i in '0123456789':
            numbers.append(int(i))
        elif i in "+*-/":
            operat.append(i)
        elif i==")" :
            oper=operat.pop()
            if oper =='+':numbers.append(numbers.pop()+numbers.pop())
            elif oper =='*':numbers.append(numbers.pop()*numbers.pop())
            elif oper =='/':numbers.append(numbers.pop(-2)/numbers.pop())
            elif oper =='-':numbers.append(numbers.pop(-2)-numbers.pop())
    return numbers.pop()
```